# Hide keyboard after change focus of Edittext in Android

Tags: java, android

Currently i am having problem of hiding keyboard when switching between Edittext.
I have hidden the keyboard with the following source code:

```
   edittext1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        edittext1.requestfocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        return true;
    }
});

edittext2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        edittext1.requestfocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        return true;
    }
})
```

But the above code not success. Every time I touch it, the keyboard show.
When holding down the edittext and moving outside the edittext area, it still show the keyboard.

I don't know how to hide the keyboard when:

1. user touch editext2 and editext2.requestfocus() from focus is edittext1
2. hold down edittext and move outside edittext, when released, the keyboard shows

Can you help me in this case?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class CompositeOnChangeFocusListener implements OnFocusChangeListener{
      private View currentFocusedView = null;
      public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
           //on a focus change.
           if(currentFocusedView != v){
               InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
               imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
           }
           //case a view in this composite has focus.
           if(hasFocus) {
              currentFocusedView = v;
           }
           //case no view using this composite is focused.
           if(v == currentFocusedView && !hasFocus){
               currentFocusedView = null;
               InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
               imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
           }
    }
}
```

This implementation of `OnFocusChangeListener` will keep track of the currently focused `View` if focus has changed it will remove the keyboard. It will also update which view is focused based on the `hasFocused` `boolean`.

```
OnFocusChangeListener listner = new CompositeOnFocusChangeListener();
//Attach the same exact listener to both.
edittext1.setOnFocusChangeListener(listner);
edittext2.setOnFocusChangeListener(listner);
```

Also try to set your top level view inside your layout xml to focusable, that way when you slide off the `EditText` focus should go to the top level view and not stick onto the `EditText`.